# How to generate LESS source maps without npm

Tags: css, less, npm, source-maps

I currently compile LESS with `lessc` (version 1.7.0) fine, but when I add `--source-map`, I get

```
SyntaxError: Cannot find module 'source-map' in /home/me/my.css
```

I suspect this may be because I did not install LESS using `npm`. How can I get source maps working?

---

The requirement (sorry): This must be able to be versioned entirely in a VCS, and not use `npm` for setup.

Comment: `lessc` requires the files in `../lib/`. Maybe you miss some of them? the error  `Cannot find module` is printed in the rhino (java) version.

Answer (score -2):

If you're not downloading the whole package at least make sure you have the libraries **LESS** needs. Checking their repo you can see source-maps is listed there so you might need those files too.

Here's the link: https://github.com/less/less.js/tree/9d3ef59cf818691cd52410879e7152e7d589de32/lib

Hope it helps.